# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop images

Tags: reactjs

I am familiar with this warning and I know what it means but I do not get it here. I have a simple image previewer, user click on right / left arrow buttons to display new images. I get this warning at this component's render function. What I believe it might be because of the image that I set as background. I have an array of images and depending on which one should be displayed on the screen, I set it as background image for entire component.

Even if I could do something like `const images = { 0: "image1", 1: "image2" }` I do not see how this solves the problem. Or maybe the problem is somewhere else.

```
const images = [
  "image1",
  "image2",
  "image3"
];

let currentImageIndex = 0;

export default function Section() {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(
    () => images[currentImageIndex]
  );

  const handleMoveNextImage = () => {
    if (currentImageIndex === images.length - 1) {
      currentImageIndex = 0;
    } else {
      currentImageIndex++;
    }
    setSelectedImage(() => images[currentImageIndex]);
  };

  const handleMovePrevImage = () => {
    if (currentImageIndex === 0) {
      currentImageIndex = images.length - 1;
    } else {
      currentImageIndex--;
    }
    setSelectedImage(() => images[currentImageIndex]);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="item-section"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${selectedImage})`,
        backgroundSize: "cover",
      }}
    >
      <div className="icons-over-img-main">
        <div className="arrow-icons-btns">
          <div
            className="placeholder-for-img-switch-arrows left"
            onClick={handleMovePrevImage}
          >
          </div>
          <div
            className="placeholder-for-img-switch-arrows"
            onClick={handleMoveNextImage}
          >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="img-position-points">
          {images.map((image, index) => (
            <div className="point">
              <div
                key={index}
                className={`${image === selectedImage && "current-point"}`}
              ></div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *topmost component returned* inside a `.map` callback is the one that needs the `key`. This:

```
{images.map((image, index) => (
  <div className="point">
    <div
        key={index}
        className={`${image === selectedImage && "current-point"}`}
      ></div>
```

should be

```
{images.map((image, index) => (
  <div className="point" key={index}>
    <div
        className={`${image === selectedImage && "current-point"}`}
      ></div>
```

Since the `images` array looks to be static, using the key for the index is safe. Declaring it as an array is just fine too. `const images = ["image1","image2","image3"];`

Also, in order to not interpolate `false` as the class name (that's not intentional, right?), use the conditional operator instead:

```
className={image === selectedImage ? "current-point" : ''}
```